# Iterate Element in Nightwatch

Tags: testing, nightwatch.js

I have a Grid View table and i want to test rows of columns with different xpath name. For instance,

```
Row Elements 1 - Test Value
Row Elements 2 - Test Value
Row Elements 3 - Test Value 


browser.useXpath()
browser.waitForElementVisible('//*[@id="asuccess"]', 1200000)
browser.waitForElementPresent('//*[@id="SearchListGridView_DXMainTable"]', 7000)
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.Sheet1.length;++i) { 
     selector = '//*[@id="SearchListGridView_DXDataRow' + i + '"]/td[4]';
    browser.expect.element(selector).text.to.contain(jsonObj.Sheet1[i].Account)
    }
```

Error Message:
Expected element  text to
       at Object.Import_Batch [as Import Batch] (C:\Users\Peter Wong\Documents\Nightwatch\Volare_Admin\import_manager.js:73:32)
       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)

Line 73 is at browser.expect.element(selector).text.to.contain(jsonObj.Sheet1[i].Account)

But return me error saying text is not element. Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

It's what the error points out, you are using a string object instead of a selector. It should work if you get rid of the `new String`.
And since you are using xpath don't forget to use `useXpath()`,

`browser.useXpath().expect.element(selector).text.to.contain(jsonObj.Sheet1[i].Account)`

Comment: I tried with following code but it is not working.   for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.Sheet1.length ;++i) { 
                selector = '//*[@id="SearchListGridView_DXDataRow' + i + '"]/td[4]';
                browser.expect.element(selector).text.to.contain(jsonObj.Sheet1[i].Account)
}

Comment: Please view my edited code above. Is it not working. Nightwatch throwing errors.

Comment: Could you post the comments here?

Comment: This is the error message: Expected element <//*[@id="SearchListGridView_DXDataRow0"]/td[4]> text to   and Code is at above.

Comment: You try putting a `waitForElementPresent` before the expect, there is a chance the element is not actually there yet and it's best practise to do so in every element interaction

Comment: I had add the waitForElementPresent but still got error message Expected element <//*[@id="SearchListGridView_DXDataRow0"]/td[4]> text to

Comment: Are you using `useXpath()` already? By default nightwatch goes for `useCss()`

Comment: Yes, I'm using xpath.

Comment: Please help me on this. I'm urgently require solution.

Comment: I believe you are missing something after `Expected element text to...`

Comment: I added the full stack trace at my original question post. Error Message: Expected element text to at Object.Import_Batch [as Import Batch] (C:\Users\Peter Wong\Documents\Nightwatch\Volare_Admin\import_manager.js:73:32) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)

Comment: Can you try to test if it works after replacing `jsonObj.Sheet1[i].Account` in `contain()` with one of the strings in the array?

Comment: Problem solved by changing the Json object field name.